# Is checkout with Credit card details possible through iPhone and Android Library?

Tags: iphone, android, paypal

**Following is my understanding:**

With the help of iPhone and Android library, we can pay the amount from one Pay pal account to another account.

**This is my doubt:**

Then how can let the user pay the amount using his credit card details in an iPhone or Android App? Are you providing any Web service APIs to achieve it?

If this is not possible, how can we let the user pay using his/her credit card?

Comment: possible to use standard API provided by payment processors or e-commerce, those are based on http. You can use http in iPhone and Android. But, unfortunately, I have seen that Apple does not approve apps which takes payment in this way. The app will not be in app store and will run on jailbroken devices only. But, there is another issue, client trust. It is hard for a normal user to differentiate between a good and a malicious app. If the user have some doubt, they will hesitate to enter card details in your app.

Comment: @sarwar: Thanks for the response. Does it mean that Paypal restricts their users to pay only through Paypal accounts, through the iPhone and Android Apps, by not providing the option of credit card payment through their Mobile Libraries?

Comment: PayPal does not restrict. When you want to put your iPhone app on Apple app store for users to download and install, you first need to submit the app to Apple.They will analyze your app and then approve or reject it. Officially, there is no restriction. But those who accepted credit card directly in their iPhone app, got their app rejected. In fact, Apple has their own API for taking payment (in app payment, what they call it). May be they want to encourage developers to use it (and they get the commission of payment done). But this is ONLY if you want to publish the app in official app store.

Comment: @sarwar: I did not literally mean "PayPal restricting the credit card payment.". When i checked the iPhone Library provided by PayPal, I found that, the library did not have the options to pay using credit card. So when PayPal has an official Library for iPhone , they should also have led the library have options to pay using credit card. This is what I meant.

Comment: Cant pay without paypal account if you want to use paypal.

Comment: Have you done the [Mobile Express Checkout Library](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk#6) in android? If yes means, help me to clear my doubts.

Comment: I have not used in Android SPK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem from the PayPal guys.

This is what the PayPal answered me:

> Currently direct credit card payments are not allowed through any of PayPal's mobile products, users will need to use a PayPal account to checkout using the libraries.
>
> To clarify, PayPal have two main
>   mobile products at the moment, Mobile
>   Express Checkout (Web) Mobile Payments
>   Library (in App). Both of these do not
>   allow for the user to checkout using
>   just a credit card yet. They will need
>   a PayPal account.
>
> I would not recommend using the
>   standard web checkout flow for mobile
>   checkout as the user interface is not
>   optimized for a mobile
>   browser/webView.

For the complete thread, visit this link:
https://www.x.com/message/193751#193751